# Looping with angularjs ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, string, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angularjs ng-repeat with div tag..i have a code with div tag as shown..i want to repeat the whole div with img src being different on the second loop..how to do this with ng-repeat directive in angularjs?

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" >
   <a href="Events.html">
     <div class="PastEvents">
       <div class="EventDate"><h5>25<br /><span>Feb</span></h5></div>
         <img src = "resources/front/images/UpComing-Event00.jpg">
         <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non massa ut tortor volutpat eleifend eu lobortis urna.</p>
      </div>
   </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why are you tagging ruby, linux, java when the question is regarding angular js

Comment: Sorry..i was asking question for the first time..Thats y got messed up @gates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
myModule.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.imageSources = ["src1", "src2", "src3"]
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="src in imageSources" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" >
    <a href="Events.html">
        <div class="PastEvents">
            <div class="EventDate"><h5>25<br /><span>Feb</span></h5></div>
                <img ng-src="{{src}}">
                <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non massa ut tortor volutpat eleifend eu lobortis urna.</p>
        </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

Basically, have your image sources in your controller and use the `ng-src` directive in your template

Comment: Can u plz tell me where i have to use 'ctrl'..Do i have to use <div ng-controller='ctrl'> in html?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying understand your question.
If you wanna display different style by the index of 'ng-repeat', you can do like following.

```
<div class="PastEvents" ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div class="EventDate"><h5>25<br /><span>Feb</span></h5></div>
  <img src = "resources/front/images/UpComing-Event00.jpg" ng-if="$index == 1"><!-- first item-->
  <img src = "resources/front/images/UpComing-Event00.jpg" ng-if="$index != 1"><!-- second and rest items-->
  <h6>Lorem ipsum</h6>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non massa ut tortor volutpat eleifend eu lobortis urna.</p>
</div>
```

If you just wanna display different resource, just using:

```
<img src = "resources/front/images/UpComing-Event{{$index}}.jpg">
```